# Typo3 extension "plugin can not be determined" exception

Tags: php, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I have created an extension and while viewing it is showing this error

> The default controller for extension "NewsInfoApi" and plugin
>   "newsinfoapi" can not be determined. Please check for
>   TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin() in your
>   ext_localconf.php***

**Here is my ext_localconf.php**

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
         'NEWS.NewsInfoApi',
         'Newsinfoapi',
         [
             'Api' => 'list'
         ],
         // non-cacheable actions
         [
             'Api' => 'list'
         ]
     );
```

What may be the problem?

Comment: These look related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22146726/367456 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/43556533/367456 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/43556533/367456 .

Comment: I have already checked this links. I have fed up with this issue, I have cleared cache, typo3temp folder etc. done everything possible, but no hope. Same error repeats. don't know what to do.

Comment: Yes this sounds like a configuration issue. If nothing else helps, one thing to do is to activate xdebug and stop when that exception is thrown and then inspecting the stack trace which configuration is missing / wrong. https://xdebug.org